# Could one gRPC server run multiple same class of service?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Consider following code

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
    .addService(new AServiceImpl(argA))
    .addService(new AServiceImpl(argB))
    .build();
```

I want this server to run two `AService` with different args, `argA` and `argB`, is it possible?

If possible, when a `AStub` call the method, which instance of service would it call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not possible, because each service is added to a map,

```
// Store per-service first, to make sure services are added/replaced atomically.
private final HashMap<String, ServerServiceDefinition> services =
    new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

by name,

```
Builder addService(ServerServiceDefinition service) {
  services.put(service.getServiceDescriptor().getName(), service);
  return this;
}
```

therefore `new AServiceImpl(argB)` will override the other.

Comment: in addition there would be a conflict on the protocol level: both instances would by default have the same descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

I had need for something similar in c# and found this question. In the end what I did was create a static concurrent dictionary to which I added different instances of a self made class that actually performed the RPC calls + added an extra parameter for all the RPC calls which specify the key of the service the client wanted the call to run off.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).